# Is there a tool for monitoring bugs for WinForm systems?

Tags: c#, winforms

We are developing a winform CRM system that is installed over several pc's in one room (over 25 stands) and all clients in that room communicates with a single server system that we also developed, using TCP/IP. The server app is connected to an SQL DataBase.
For over 3 months now, awe are having a huge bug that causes all clients in the room to crash, and we have no idea why.
Can anyone please tell me if there is a tool for developers (even paid), that can help us monitor the clients and the server and give us some information about the cause of these crashes ?

Comment: Did you put any logging or monitoring into your home-grown server and/or CRM system?

Comment: We put all kinds of logs, but they tell us nothing to help find and fix these crashes

Comment: Evaluate the event logs.

Comment: Do they all crash simultaneously?  Is there any commonality in the occurences of the crash(es)?  Is it reproducible?  If your current logs aren't telling you anything, then either a) your logging is incomplete or b) it's something outside the application/server.  Most likely it's a).  The more complex the system, the easier it is to inadvertently swallow root cause exceptions (usually by throwing a new exception and not carrying the original exception and/or stack trace forward).

Comment: Instead of asking for a tool recommendation ([off-topic on StackOverlow I'm afraid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), you would be better off describing what exactly happens. If you have logging configured, you should certainly have exceptions logged before your apps crash. If nothing else, Windows event log should contain application errors. Even if you didn't ask for a tool recommendation, the question is simply too broad in its current form.

Comment: Soory about that, I didn't know this is an off-topic...

Answer (score 2):

Do proper log writing for all relevant transactions, which is free to use

Answer (score -1):

One of the best for desktop applications, I found was [DeskMetrics](http://deskmetrics.com/) (paid) .

There are available any kind of conigurations, like:  exception, custom action... logs and also ploting over them and other data.

Comment: Why this tool and not one of the thousand others? The site is extremely uninformational, not a single word of what it does and no explanation from you why it will help OP.

Comment: @CodeCaster: because this is a just a *one* example of many. any probem with that ?

Comment: It looks like this is for analytics purpose only. Are you sure it can help us find the cause for this bug ?

Comment: @CodeCaster: not being informative site, is a subjective, and, by the way, I share *my personal* positive experience with that tool.

Comment: It's exactly the reason why SE doesn't allow such questions. It invites spam, and it's no place to compile a complete, up-to-date list of tools for such tasks. And you added your second sentence to your answer after or while I added my comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster: so, in your opinion, writing "Do it yourself" is more appropriate for SO then providing tools wich can help accomplish what you are searching for ?

Comment: @LiranFridman: unfortunately they completely changed the site, and con not find detailed information, but I used exception patterns. I could also define my custom Actions and og them to, after plot them together. Give it a try, only in this way you will know if it fits your needs.

Comment: I scheduled a demo. Let's see what it does...